# Asking questions about material you wish to publish.

Tags: discussion

Suppose I have a proof that I wish to publish.  If I were to post the result and ask if there were any known proofs, and someone were to give a proof similar to mine, could I still publish my proof(if the proof were not published somewhere already)?

In general, should you ask about material you are currently researching, and want to publish on in the future?

Related: If you post a solution, does this constitute as "dibs" on publishing that answer.  That is, suppose you post a proof that is worth publishing.  Is there any protection against that being "borrowed" into some one else's paper?

I am pretty new to the profession, so I am sorry if these are silly questions.  Maybe no one does that?

Comment: See the footer of this page: "user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required". (Questions are also user contributions, by the way.) See also the discussion [Do I cite mathstackexchange in my paper?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4259/85506)

Comment: Yup.  That will do.